# Retrieve xml node value using xmltable 11g for multi items

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery, xmltype, xmltable

Hope this is very simple, but I am missing something.

This is my XML :

```
 <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?><PFA>
       <Person id="11" action="add" date="20-Nov-2012">
          <Gender>Male</Gender>
          <ActiveStatus>Active</ActiveStatus>
          <Deceased>Yes</Deceased>
            <RoleDetail>
             <Roles RoleType="Primary Occupation">
                <OccTitle OccCat="16">Deceased</OccTitle>
             </Roles>
             <Roles RoleType="Previous Roles">
                <OccTitle SinceMonth="Nov" SinceYear="2010" ToMonth="Jan" ToYear="2011" OccCat="16">Candidate</OccTitle>
                <OccTitle SinceMonth="Mar" SinceYear="2005" ToYear="2005" OccCat="16">Candidate,23</OccTitle>
                <OccTitle OccCat="16">President</OccTitle>
                <OccTitle SinceDay="22" SinceMonth="Oct" SinceYear="1993" ToDay="15" ToMonth="Mar" ToYear="2003" OccCat="1">President </OccTitle>
                <OccTitle OccCat="7">Supreme Commander</OccTitle>
                <OccTitle SinceDay="08" SinceMonth="Dec" SinceYear="1976" ToDay="14" ToMonth="Jul" ToYear="1978" OccCat="1">Prime Minister </OccTitle>
             </Roles>
          </RoleDetail>
        </Person>
      </PFA>
```

---

I am querying this xml to store the values in my table.

My Query -

```
SELECT t.personid, t.occtitle,r.roleid,t.sinceday,t.sincemonth,t.sinceyear,t.today,t.tomonth,t.toyear,t.occcat
FROM xml_files p,master_roletypelists r,
     XMLTable(
      'for $i in PFA/Person/RoleDetail/Roles/OccTitle
       return <row>
       {
          $i/../../../@id,
          $i/../@RoleType,
          $i/@SinceDay,
          $i/@SinceMonth,
          $i/@SinceYear,
          $i/@ToDay,
          $i/@ToMonth,
          $i/@ToYear,
          $i/@OccCat
       } 
       </row>' 
      PASSING p.filecontent
      COLUMNS 
              personid  number PATH '@id',
              occtitle    VARCHAR2(4000)  PATH '.',
              RoleType    VARCHAR2(2000)  PATH '@RoleType',
              sinceday    VARCHAR2(2000)  PATH '@SinceDay',
              sincemonth    VARCHAR2(2000)  PATH '@SinceMonth',
              sinceyear    VARCHAR2(2000)  PATH '@SinceYear',
              today    VARCHAR2(2000)  PATH '@ToDay',
              tomonth    VARCHAR2(2000)  PATH '@ToMonth',
              toyear    VARCHAR2(2000)  PATH '@ToYear',
              occcat    VARCHAR2(2000)  PATH '@OccCat'

     ) t where t.roletype = r.rolename
;
```

But for this I am getting the column 'OCCTITLE' as null.

Please help me to modify my query to get the OccTitle node value as well.
For example in OccTitle column in first row I am supposed to get the value "Deceased" instead of null.

If this is not the way to do this please help me to correct it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never included the `<OccTitle/>` element. For example, use

```
for $i in PFA/Person/RoleDetail/Roles/OccTitle
   return <row>
   {
      $i/../../../@id,
      $i/../@RoleType,
      $i/@SinceDay,
      $i/@SinceMonth,
      $i/@SinceYear,
      $i/@ToDay,
      $i/@ToMonth,
      $i/@ToYear,
      $i/@OccCat,
      $i (: was missing :)
   } 
   </row>
```

This will include the whole element. If you're only interested in the data, replace that line with `data($i)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It worked perfectly for me when I used it as per mentioned. But when I tried using:    for $i in PFA/Person/RoleDetail/Roles/OccTitle return <row> { $i/../../../@id,$i(:included), $i/../@RoleType, $i/@SinceDay, $i/@SinceMonth, $i/@SinceYear, $i/@ToDay, $i/@ToMonth, $i/@ToYear, $i/@OccCat } </row>.  This give me an error like "Error during parsing the xquery expression". Since I am a novice and not an expert could you please let me know why it happened to throw an error in that case.

Comment: When constructing elements with attributes, all attributes have to occur _before_ the first non-attribute content. Move `$i` to the last position in the sequence (so, immediately before the closing `}`. In your comment, you're missing the dash when closing it (`:)`).

Comment: @Jens..Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation and I really appreciate your help.